# mysql / php - 3 tables (if number exists)

Tags: php, html, mysql, random

I have a problem,

i´m building an own register form for a browsergame.

I have to place the planet on register, that the user get.

so i have: 9 galaxies, each galaxy has 400 systems and each system can have up to 15 planets.
tables: galaxy, system, planet.

right now im creating rand numbers, it works fine.
Its creating the Planets but i dont know how to check
if a galaxy is full, or if a system have already 15 planets
to take the next.

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM planet WHERE name = "Earth"

Comment: @sashkello How does that help things?

Comment: What else do you suggest? This is the answer to the question as it is stated.

Comment: Yeah, OK, it should be: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM system WHERE name = "Systemname"

Answer (score 0):

On the SQL side assuming `system_id` is the foreign key linking `planets` to `systems`:

```
SELECT system_id, COUNT(system_id) 
FROM planets 
GROUP BY system_id;
```

This should give you each system (ID) with the number of planets in it.

```
system_id  |  count
1             12
2             10
...           ...
```

On the php side, you'd then use this array to see if any have reached 15 and stop assigning to it.